# WSO2 Custom claim handler not being called for password grant_type

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have been using WSO2IS as OIDC provider. I have implemented a custom claim handler which is working fine and being invoked when WSO2 receives grant_type "Authorization_code". The problem started when a Service Provider sent a request with `grant_type=password`. In this case, WSO2 succesfully authenticated the user and returned the JWT but... without custom claim as WSO2 did not invoke the custom claim handler.

This is the configuration I did in file `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/application-authentication.xml` for custom claim handler which is being invoked for `grant_type=authorization_code`.

```
<ClaimHandler>com.wso2.carbon.identity.custom.claim.handler.CustomClaimHandler</ClaimHandler>
```

this the debug log from WSO2:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,199] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager} - 
>   Created singleton instance for
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager  TID:
>   [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,200] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager} -  Get
>   first priority handler for the given handler list.  TID: [-1234] []
>   [2018-04-06 11:34:38,200] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager} -  Get
>   first priority handler :
>   DefaultAuthenticationManager(org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.AuthenticationManager)
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,205] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Access Token
>   request received for Client ID EjQvbCf0pclp6eVO5lxTq23_lxQa, User ID
>   userldap, Scope : [ openid, email] and Grant Type : password  TID:
>   [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,205] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.clientauth.AbstractClientAuthHandler}
>   -  Can authenticate with client ID and Secret. Client ID: EjQvbCf0pclp6eVO5lxTq23_lxQa  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06
>   11:34:38,205] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.clientauth.AbstractClientAuthHandler}
>   -  Grant type : password Strict client validation set to : null  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,206] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Client
>   credentials were fetched from the database.  TID: [-1234] []
>   [2018-04-06 11:34:38,206] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Successfully
>   authenticated the client with client id : EjQvbCf0pclp6eVO5lxTq23_lxQa
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,207] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} -  Oauth App
>   validation success for consumer key: EjQvbCf0pclp6eVO5lxTq23_lxQa 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,209] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener}
>   -  Pre authenticator is called in IdentityMgtEventListener  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,210] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.dao.CacheBackedLocalClaimDAO}
>   -  Cache hit for local claim list for tenant: -1234  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,210] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.DefaultClaimMetadataStore}
>   -  Assigned mapped attribute : ref from user store domain : PRIMARY for claim : http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountDisabled in tenant
>   : -1234  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,215] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.dao.CacheBackedLocalClaimDAO}
>   -  Cache hit for local claim list for tenant: -1234  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,215] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener}
>   -  post get user claim values is called in IdentityMgtEventListener  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,215] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityUtil} -  Error while
>   reading user store property CaseInsensitiveUsername. Considering as
>   case sensitive.  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,215] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.store.InMemoryIdentityDataStore}
>   -  Loaded UserIdentityClaimsDO from cache for user :userldap with claims: {}  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,215] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery.handler.AdminForcedPasswordResetHandler}
>   -  Handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,215] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery.handler.AdminForcedPasswordResetHandler}
>   -  PreAuthenticate - AdminForcedPasswordResetHandler for user : userldap@carbon.super  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,215] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityUtil} -  Error while
>   reading user store property CaseInsensitiveUsername. Considering as
>   case sensitive.  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,216] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery.handler.AccountConfirmationValidationHandler}
>   -  PreAuthenticate  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,216] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.dao.CacheBackedLocalClaimDAO}
>   -  Cache hit for local claim list for tenant: -1234  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,217] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.DefaultClaimMetadataStore}
>   -  Assigned mapped attribute : accountLock from user store domain : PRIMARY for claim : http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked in
>   tenant : -1234  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,218] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.dao.CacheBackedLocalClaimDAO}
>   -  Cache hit for local claim list for tenant: -1234  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,218] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener}
>   -  post get user claim values is called in IdentityMgtEventListener  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,218] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityUtil} -  Error while
>   reading user store property CaseInsensitiveUsername. Considering as
>   case sensitive.  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,218] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.store.InMemoryIdentityDataStore}
>   -  Loaded UserIdentityClaimsDO from cache for user :userldap with claims: {}  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,218] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.processors.RandomPasswordProcessor}
>   -  Cache Key not found for Random Password Container  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,222] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener}
>   -  post authenticator is called in IdentityMgtEventListener  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,222] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.processors.RandomPasswordProcessor}
>   -  Cache Key not found for Random Password Container  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,223] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.processors.RandomPasswordProcessor}
>   -  Cache Key not found for Random Password Container  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,223] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler}
>   -  Token request with Password Grant Type received. Username : userldap@carbon.superScope : email openid , Authentication State :
>   true  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,223] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.callback.OAuthCallbackHandlerRegistry}
>   -  OAuthCallbackHandler was found for the callback. Class Name : org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.callback.DefaultCallbackHandler
>   Resource Owner : userldap@carbon.super Client Id :
>   EjQvbCf0pclp6eVO5lxTq23_lxQa Scope : email openid   TID: [-1234] []
>   [2018-04-06 11:34:38,223] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.callback.OAuthCallbackHandlerRegistry}
>   -  OAuthCallbackHandler was found for the callback. Class Name : org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.callback.DefaultCallbackHandler
>   Resource Owner : userldap@carbon.super Client Id :
>   EjQvbCf0pclp6eVO5lxTq23_lxQa Scope : email openid   TID: [-1234] []
>   [2018-04-06 11:34:38,223] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Added
>   OAuthTokenReqMessageContext to threadlocal  TID: [-1234] []
>   [2018-04-06 11:34:38,223] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityUtil} -  Error while
>   reading user store property CaseInsensitiveUsername. Considering as
>   case sensitive.  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,223] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  SP wise token
>   expiry time feature is applied for tenant id : -1234and consumer key :
>   EjQvbCf0pclp6eVO5lxTq23_lxQa  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06
>   11:34:38,224] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler}
>   -  Service Provider specific expiry time enabled for application : EjQvbCf0pclp6eVO5lxTq23_lxQa. Application access token expiry time :
>   null, User access token expiry time : null, Refresh token expiry time
>   : null  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,224] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler}
>   -  OAuth application id : EjQvbCf0pclp6eVO5lxTq23_lxQa, access token validity time in milliseconds : 3600000  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06
>   11:34:38,224] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityUtil}
>   -  Error while reading user store property CaseInsensitiveUsername. Considering as case sensitive.  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06
>   11:34:38,230] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler}
>   -  Infinite lifetime Access Token e88de89f-70d4-33d5-b447-5cd0135fd682 found in cache  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,230] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Cleared
>   OAuthTokenReqMessageContext  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,230]
>   DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} - 
>   Access token issued to client Id: EjQvbCf0pclp6eVO5lxTq23_lxQa
>   username: userldap@carbon.super and scopes: email openid   TID:
>   [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,230] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} -  Issuing
>   ID token for client: EjQvbCf0pclp6eVO5lxTq23_lxQa  TID: [-1234] []
>   [2018-04-06 11:34:38,230] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.processors.RandomPasswordProcessor}
>   -  Cache Key not found for Random Password Container  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,232] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  Loading Basic Application Data of AdministradorOmnicanalidad  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,232] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  ApplicationID: 21 ApplicationName: AdministradorOmnicanalidad UserName: userldap TenantDomain: carbon.super  TID: [-1234] []
>   [2018-04-06 11:34:38,232] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  Reading Clients of Application 21  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,233] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  Reading Steps of Application 21  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,236] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  Reading Claim Mappings of Application 21  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,237] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  Reading Role Mapping of Application 21  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,241] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityUtil}
>   -  Error while reading user store property CaseInsensitiveUsername. Considering as case sensitive.  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06
>   11:34:38,241] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO}
>   -  Retrieve access token for tokenId: e88de89f-70d4-33d5-b447-5cd0135fd682 with flag includeExpired: false 
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,244] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.DefaultIDTokenBuilder} - 
>   Using issuer https://localhost:9445/oauth2/token Subject userldap ID
>   Token life time 3600 Current time 1523032478 Nonce Value null
>   Signature Algorithm RS256   TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,244]
>   DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.SAMLAssertionClaimsCallback} -
>   Adding claims for user userldap@carbon.super to id token.  TID:
>   [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,247] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.SAMLAssertionClaimsCallback} -
>   User attributes not found in cache. Trying to retrieve attribute for
>   user userldap@carbon.super  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,249]
>   DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  Loading Basic Application Data of AdministradorOmnicanalidad  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,251] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  ApplicationID: 21 ApplicationName: AdministradorOmnicanalidad UserName: userldap TenantDomain: carbon.super  TID: [-1234] []
>   [2018-04-06 11:34:38,251] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  Reading Clients of Application 21  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,251] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  Reading Steps of Application 21  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,255] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  Reading Claim Mappings of Application 21  TID: [-1234] [] [2018-04-06 11:34:38,256] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   -  Reading Role Mapping of Application 21

If someone can point what did I miss, or what else I can try, It would be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim Handlers are engaged as part of the authentications process in the authentication framework that resides within the Identity Server.

When you use the authorization grant type, user authentication is handled via the authentication framework. This also means that any claims added/modified using a custom claims handler will be engaged.

However, when you use the password grant type, user authentication and claim retrieval happens via the respective user store the user resides in. Since this authentication does not happen through the authentication framework your custom claim handler will not be engaged.

Comment: Good to know that it is the expected behaviour. But how do I handle such scenario where I need to call a third party service to get the claim?

Comment: You can use an extension like https://github.com/mefarazath/OIDCCustomClaimHandler to populate custom claims into the id_token

Comment: Hi @farasath, I need to call custom authenticator and custom claim handler in case of password grant or request path authenticator. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Is there any specific reason write a custom claim handler for OIDC?

If you want to get custom claims with OIDC you could follow the below steps.

1. Go to management console->claims->Add->Add external claims->select dialect URI as http://wso2.org/oidc/claim, give your custom claim URI as External Claim URI, map the appropriate local claim.
2. Once you successfully added the custom claim under OIDC dialect, you have to mention the newly added custom claim URI in the registry under openid scope.The path is below.
   Registry->Browse->/_system/config/oidc and then click on Add button of the properties. There you could see the scope values.

Comment: Yes. I need to call a third party service to get some claims.